# Combine two integers (one containing the integer part, the other the decimal part) into a floating point number

Tags: c#, floating-point

How do I produce a `double` value by combining two integers? I already tried searching but I can't find the answer that I'm looking for.

It goes like this:

```
int wholeNumber = 2;
int decimal = 25;
```

I want to make a `double` that results into `2.25`.

Comment: what if decimal was 5?  Would that be 2.5 or 2.05?

Comment: It will not work if you want 2.025, as an int don't store leading zeroes.

Comment: decimal is a keyword of C#.

Comment: You could try concatenating two strings ("2" and "25") and converting that to double using the Parse function.  I agree with the comments above, the lack of leading zeros can give you headaches.

Comment: I'd like to point out also that using double or float may introduce a rounding error if the value cannot properly represented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheating solution goes like this:

```
string number = wholeNumber + "." + decimal
double doubleNumber = Double.Parse(number);
```

Clean solution would involve checking how many values you have in the 'decimal', dividing by 10^amount and adding them

As was pointed out - decimal seperator is cultural-specific - so the completly correct version is

```
string number = wholeNumber + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSepar‌​ator + decimal
double doubleNumber = Double.Parse(number);
```

(I kept the top one because its easier to understand)

Comment: No idea how I'd handle that. Math.Abs, or negate everything. I guess the OP knows how that should work for his own implementation.

Comment: Don't forget the decimal separator is culture-specific.

Comment: Instead of using ".", you might want to replace that by 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`

Comment: Edited accordingly. I kept both because the top one is easier to understand even if its not entirely correct.

Comment: Actually we're just trying to convert a Time into a double. Having a negative value is impossible so we guess that solves it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Or... just use Maths:

```
double d = wholeNumber + (double)decimal / 100;
```

Seriously...

Comment: That all depends on how the OP's question is defined right? What would you expect? Do you really think it takes string concatenation + parsing to assemble an integer part and a decimal part into a floating point number?

Comment: We're only trying to convert time into a double so we guess that the first answer is good enough. Thank you so much for the answers.